# How to push to next view controller from xib select button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I would like to push to `ParcelPickUpViewController` after I clicked a button in `LocationDetailsTableViewCell` xib. But I've written the code below and it able to run. But the result won't happen at all. Need help on this issue. Thanks.

In `LocationDetailsTableViewCell.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *viewController;
```

In `LocationDetailsTableViewCell.m`

```
- (IBAction)selectBtn:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ParcelPickUpViewController *vc = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "pickUpVC"];
    [self.viewController pushViewController:vc animated: YES];
    [self.viewController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Is the `vc` is nil? Put break point and check it by enter `po vc` in your console after the breakpoint triggered

Comment: instead of passing a vc to your tableViewCell, reach out with a delegate to your viewController from your tableViewCell and push from there.

Comment: If it is XIB then why do you write storyboard line coding?

Comment: self.secondViewController =
                    [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController"
                                                               bundle:nil];
   [self presentViewController:self.secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: ParcelPickUpViewController is xib or Storyboard scene

Comment: @Tj3n there is value in it  `<ParcelPickUpViewController: 0x7fbb2434cff0>`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik ParcelPickUpViewController is storyboard, LocationDetailsTableViewCell is xib

Comment: @Edmund - are you embed the Navigation controller

Comment: @dirtydanee any example to do it?

Comment: @Edmund here is a simple example https://gist.github.com/austinzheng/db58036c4eb825e63e88 , but if you search a bit on SO, you will find tons of examples.

Comment: @Edmund - check the below option 2 answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have button in UITableViewCell.Now you want to navigate to next view from the button click.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        cell = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    cell.btnSelct.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.btnSelct addTarget:self action:@selector(selectBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
} 

- (IBAction)selectBtn:(id)sender
{
    //This is for XIB
    ParcelPickUpViewController *vc = [[ParcelPickUpViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"pickUpVC" bundle:nil];

   //If you use storyboard
   UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   ParcelPickUpViewController *vc = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"parcelpickup"];

   [self.viewController pushViewController:vc animated: YES];

}
```

[image]

Comment: are you seen this ` UINavigationController *viewController` is create the object for navigation controller, not allocated the memory

Comment: So I've to put this code in the class that I show xib?

Comment: @Edmund - try this `[self.NavigationController pushViewController:vc animated: YES];`

Comment: Edmund have you got the solution?

Comment: Do you use storyboard?

Comment: @user3182143 I've use storyboard. `ParcelDropOffViewController` is the storyboard that using `LocationDetailsTableViewCell` xib, wanted to click the button in xib  to  `ParcelPickUpViewController`

Comment: Can you just show your Identity Inspector of ParcelPickUpViewController?

Comment: Take the screenshot and show it here.I will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try This ...

```
 - (IBAction)selectBtn:(id)sender {
    ParcelPickUpViewController *vc = [[HomeScreenVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"pickUpVC" bundle:nil];
    [self.viewController pushViewController:vc animated: YES];
    [self.viewController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

**option 2**

you are created the Navigation controller not allocated the memory of your instance navigation controller, so do like

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ParcelPickUpViewController *vc = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "pickUpVC"];
 self.viewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[self.viewController pushViewController:vc animated: YES];
[self.viewController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

if you no need the `setNavigationBarHidden` then use like

**option 3**

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ParcelPickUpViewController *vc = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "pickUpVC"];

[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: is not in `ParcelPickUpViewController *vc = [[HomeScreenVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"pickUpVC" bundle:nil];` it is in `ParcelPickUpViewController *vc = [[ParcelPickUpViewController alloc]init];`

Comment: @Edmund - try with option 3

Comment: @Edmund - better you will attach your projec

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Couldn't attach it as security issues =(

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** Make sure you have set the `isInitialViewController`(the first controller you want to display when app launch) in `storyboard`.

[image]

**(2)** If you did not add `UINavigationController` in `storyboard`, create it programeticaly and set it as `rootViewController` w.r.t your `InitialViewController` in **app delegate** `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:Nil];


    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your_First_View_Controller_Identifier"];

    UINavigationController *rootNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = rootNavigationController;

    return YES;
}
```

**(3)** While navigating to your `ParcelPickUpViewController` just simply add below code:

```
- (IBAction)selectBtn:(id)sender {

    ParcelPickUpViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "pickUpVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated: YES];
}
```